# Combine two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Let say I have 2 `numpy` arrays

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

With this, I want to create a 2-dimensional array as below

[image]

Is there any method available to directly achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is about writing the Cartesian product. In numpy, you can write it using `repeat` and `tile`:

```py
out = np.c_[np.repeat(x, len(y)), np.tile(y, len(x))]
```

Python's builtin `itertools` module has a method designed for this: `product`:

```py
from itertools import product
out = np.array(list(product(x,y)))
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 4]])
```